# Double free when use pcap_close and fclose simultaneously

Tags: c, libpcap, fclose, double-free

```
FILE* file = fopen(some file)

pcap_t* pd = pcap_fopen_offline(file)

pcap_close(pd)

fclose(file)
```

This code occurs double free error.

Could you explain about this happening?

My Guess is that pd and file pointers are sharing some datas.

Comment: They share the file descriptor. I checked file descriptor of *file via fileno, before and after pcap_close call. Then, the file descriptor had changed 3 to -1. Still *file is available but system doesn't have the file descriptor. Still, I don't know why this situation make a double free, but using pcap_close and fclose together can occur some problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says, the `pcap_close` function closes the files associated with the `pcap_t` structure passed to it. Closing the file again with `fclose` is an error.